# _foreign_keys error with Camelot

Tags: python, sqlite, orm

I tried Camelot 10.07.02-c2-4build1 with SQLAlchemy 0.6.4-3 from the Ubuntu 11.04 repos and I get the following stacktrace, when I try to reference a foreign key in the table view:

```
ERROR:camelot.view.model_thread.signal_slot_model_thread:exception caught in model thread while executing get_columns -> QueryTableProxy.setColumns
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/view/model_thread/signal_slot_model_thread.py", line 31, in execute
    result = self._request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/view/proxy/collection_proxy.py", line 272, in get_columns
    self._columns = columns_getter()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/view/model_thread/__init__.py", line 56, in wrapper
    return original_function( *args, **kwargs )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/admin/object_admin.py", line 418, in get_columns
    for field in self.list_display]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/view/model_thread/__init__.py", line 56, in wrapper
    return original_function( *args, **kwargs )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/view/elixir_admin.py", line 198, in get_field_attributes
    foreign_keys = list(property._foreign_keys)
AttributeError: 'RelationshipProperty' object has no attribute '_foreign_keys'
```

My code is essential the following:

```
class Customer(Entity):
    name = Field(Unicode(200))
    packages = OneToMany("Package")

    class Admin(EntityAdmin):
        list_display = ['name']

class Package(Entity):
    interval_months = Field(Integer)
    customer = ManyToOne("Customer")

    class Admin(EntityAdmin):    
        list_display = ['interval_months', 'customers'] # here is the error
```

Searching gave me some hint in a [mailinglist](http://groups.google.com/group/project-camelot/browse_thread/thread/c112cc070aa76683/5bfd84ef6e0f400d?utoken=3Xh2wTIAAADAx5jR-5hTpxDQX664zM7eG4nXrcOqdXIt_9ItGQJbBZXGw71Aich793OdvKQzb1NYYPFDy0QGdfpgd9f8rWFq), but I do not really understand how I can fix that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of SQLAlchemy has changed API that Camelot uses, therefore Camelot needs to be updated.